# Finding the image by a given area and function

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Area:
$${z \in C:Rez>0,Imz>0}$$

function:
$$w(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$$

Find the image?

Solution:

fist we find where the function goes through the infinite value:
$$w(-i)=\infty$$

that mean that the image is going to be a circle ?

After that I am not sure what we have to do. *What is the algorithmic way of solving these problems?*

From my notes I see that one way is to get a number of points and see what happens to them, but I am not quite familiar of how that works.

The other way is to:

Find the inverse point of the $\infty$ point which is $\overline{i}=-i$ so:

$$z_{0}(-i)=..=0$$
After that w grab a random point and:
$$r_{0}=|w(random_point=0)-z_{0}(-i)|=..=1$$
And we have a circle which C(0, 1), which is a bit of a solution.

The real solution is {C(0,1), Imz<0}.

But I have missed that what do I have to do to proove that, what did I do wrong, what am I missing ?!?!?!

Answer (score 1):

Hint...rearrange to make $z$ the subject and put $w=u+iv$

Apply the given constraints of $z$ and obtain conditions for $u,v$

Comment: $$w(z)=\frac{u+iv-i}{u+iv+i}$$, no clue what that gives me. What constaints does z have ?

Comment: The real and imaginary parts of $z$ are positive

Answer (score 1):

Hint: solve for $z$ then multiply by the conjugate of the denominator to isolate the $\operatorname{Re/Im}$ parts:

$$\begin{align}
w=\cfrac{z-i}{z+i} \implies z = \cfrac{-i(w+1)}{w-1} \cdot \cfrac{\bar w - 1}{\bar w -1} &= \cfrac{-i w \bar w + i w - i \bar w + i}{|w-1|^2} \\
 &= \cfrac{-2 \operatorname{Im}(w) + i\,(1 - |w|^2)}{|w-1|^2} 
\end{align}
$$

Since the denominator $|w-1|^2 \gt 0\,$:

- $\operatorname{Re}(z) \gt 0 \iff -2 \operatorname{Im}(w) \gt 0$
- $\operatorname{Im}(z) \gt 0 \iff 1 - |w|^2 \gt 0$